# When using examples in PyBehave can you enter them into a table within a step?

Tags: python-behave

One of my steps in my behave test generates a CSV file from a table within the step example below

```
Scenario: Some_name for attribute 1



  Given I add a file with the following data for attribute_1
        |Identifier|value_1|value_2|attribute_1|
        |1234      |yes    |no     |no         | 
    When I process the file
    Then a thing happens 
    And attribute_1 is processed correctly
```

The system under test needs me to run several tests with different values for attribute in order to save me having to have multiple tests written out I would like to use the outline/examples approach.

Does behave allow me to enter a parameter for a table value? eg

```
 Scenario Outline: Some_name for attributes
        Given I add a file with the following data for attribute <attribute>
            |Identifier|value_1|value_2|<attribute>|
            |1234      |yes    |no     |no         | 
        When I process the file
        Then a thing happens
        And attribute <attribute >is processed correctly 

        Examples:
            |attribute  |
            |attribute_1|
            |attribute_2|
```

If it does not is there an alternative way of doing this using behave I know there are hacky ways I could make this work but want to see if Behave will handle this without needing to code workarounds.

Comment: Yes, that is build into the Gherkin: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html#table

Comment: tried this behaviour it isnt working, passes <attribute> as the value not the example value.